# Round corners on buttons in button group bootstrap with multiple rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm currently looking to put round corners on the last and first button in the in a button group. At the moment we have the first and last button in the group rounded, but we would like to have it like this on each row. 
This is the current CSS that is used for it (from standard button-groups.less from bootstrap) :

```
.btn-group > .btn:first-child:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle) {
border-top-right-radius: 0;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px;
```

HTML (directive):

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-filter" 
    ng-repeat="option in options track by $index" 
    ng-class="{active:isSelected(option)}"
    ng-click="toggleSelect(option)">{{option.caption}}</button>
</div>
```

The result at this moment is: 
[Screenshot of the (not-)rounded buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dCt8.png)

How could we accomplish that the first and last button on each row of the btn group gets rounded corners?

Comment: Please share html code as well.

Comment: What you want is impossible, css is not aware of "new row". Put them all in one line or use script to set additional button classes.

Comment: @kmg added HTML now too.

Comment: @skobaljic  there is no space to put them all on one line.. How would I write the script to detect the last and first button in the row?

Comment: Will the number of items in a row be consistent?

Comment: @sol it will not be, because when change the window size of your browser the btn group also adapts..

Comment: You could use `nth-child` and media queries, or a script if it's going to be easier

Answer (score 0):

You can use script to detect rows this way (or similar):

```js
function detectRows() {
    $('.detect-rows').each(function(i) {
     var thisContainer = $(this);
        var row = 0;
        var offsetY = -1;
        var previousButton = null;
        var thisButtons = thisContainer.find('button');
        var totalButtons = thisButtons.length;
        thisButtons.each(function(j) {
            var thisButton = $(this);
            var thisOffsetY = thisButton.offset().top;
            console.log('thisOffsetY: ' + thisOffsetY)
            if( thisOffsetY>offsetY ) {
                offsetY = thisOffsetY;
                row++;
                thisButton.attr('data-first', 'Y');
                if( previousButton ) {
                    previousButton.attr('data-last', 'Y');
                };
            };
            if( totalButtons==(j+1) ) {
             thisButton.attr('data-last', 'Y');
            };
            thisButton.attr('data-row', row);
            previousButton = thisButton;
        });
    });
};
$(window).on('resize', detectRows)
detectRows();
```

```css
button {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
button[data-row="1"] {
    color: green;
}
button[data-row="2"] {
    color: red;
}
button[data-row="3"] {
    color: orange;
}
button[data-first="Y"] {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
button[data-last="Y"] {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="detect-rows">
    <button>I BUTTON</button> <button>I BUTTON</button> <button>I BUTTON</button> <button>I BUTTON</button> <button>I BUTTON</button> <button>I BUTTON</button> <button>I BUTTON</button> <button>I BUTTON</button> <button>I BUTTON</button> <button>I BUTTON</button> <button>I BUTTON</button> <button>I BUTTON</button>
</div>
```

After that, you have attributes for CSS styling.

Also on [JSFidle](https://jsfiddle.net/42350v8f/1/).